# Dynamic ports with Azure Ad Authentication

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-2.0

I am developing an ASP.Net Core 2.0 application in Azure Service Fabric. This application uses Azure Ad Authentication. This authentication requires a registered reply URL in the Azure portal. Service fabric however assigns a port to my application based on the available ports. How can I implement this way of authentication with dynamically assigned ports without registering over one hundred different reply URLs? The ports are currently resolved through the use of the Service Fabric reverse proxy.

In my startup I have entered my Azure Ad config in `ConfigureServices` with:"

```
services.AddAzureAd(options =>
{
     Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
})
```

My appsettings contains:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.com",
    "TenantId": "AD tenant id (GUID)",
    "ClientId": "registered app id (GUID)",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: How will your clients find the application?

Comment: Through the Service Fabric reverse proxy. I will add it to the original post.

Comment: Can you run a dedicated application & service that hosts the reply endpoint?

Comment: @HiredMind That does not work since they are not equal and the RP address does not have to point to the same server.

Comment: @LoekD That sounds like a lot more trouble than it should be, I also don't have a clue how that should be implemented by just using the asp.net core middleware.

Comment: Why would you be worried about the dynamic ports if your clients interact with the service via SF reverse proxy? Don't the proxy work on the same port for all the apps in the cluster?

Comment: @KirylZ The address of the reverse proxy is mydomain.com:19081. Whenever one of my services is trying to do authentication it uses 10.0.0.x:port. So it uses the internal ip and port number where I want to use the external ip and port.

Comment: So, if you specify mydomain.com:19081/signin-oidc as ReplyUrl in App Registration and enable Session Persistence in LB Rule, wouldn't it work? Also, could you please specify the 'layout' details - how many AD app registrations you have, how many app types are registered in SF cluster of yours, how many tenants in AD your services are tied with, etc.

Comment: The reason that it doesn't work is that my service specifies `10.0.0.4:20041/signin-oidc` as callback path instead of the `mydomain.com:19081/app/service/signin-oidc`. In my app settings I have specified the callback path as `/signin-oidc`. I have a total of 3 app registrations for my cluster. Only one of them is used for the authentication. In my cluster there are two different app types defined. One of them has one instance which includes the service that is trying to authenticate.

Comment: Umm.. why would you specify the internal ip address along with the port as a replyurl? Is your app intended to be used private?

Comment: That is the issue here. The oidc middleware specifies the replyurl. As far as I've tried it is not possible to configure an absolute uri. Perhaps there is a way to configure the RP to preserve the host header, but I haven't found a way to do that.

Comment: Interesting... In my current project, we set up App Registration beforehand (with absolute uri), and then we pass the app id from AD as clientid to configure OpenIdMiddleware. Would you mind sharing the way you do configuration in your Asp.Net Core project?

Comment: @KirylZ I also pass the clientid, but that is used for Azure to verify the token. Verifying the token is not the issue here. The issue is Azures response and that it cannot reply to my service because the address is wrong. I have edited my post with the configuration I'm using.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding that AddAzureId extension. What's a precise version of .net core you have installed on your machine?

Comment: ASP.Net Core 2.0

Comment: Please, run "dotnet --info" in the command line to get the exact version.

Comment: @KirylZ .Net Core 2.0.0

Comment: @WouterB Digging deeper I've figured how you could tune the oidc middleware to use the reverse proxy as replyurl. I hooked up my own delegate into OpenIdConnectEvents.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event and changed context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri to point at the reverse proxy. I can add the code into the answer if you want me to.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here is my suggestion.

**Use SF reverse proxy url as ReplyUrl**
You don't need to register every possible private address along with the port in ReplyUrls section for a given app registration. As you communicate with the service via SF Reverse Proxy, put its address as a reply url.

**Adjust the code to build a correct redirect_uri**
There is a change you'll need to apply to make sure that redirect_uri would be pointing at your reverse proxy rather than local ip. The exact code depends on many factors, include asp.net core build installed on your machine, but here is the prototype that I've got working on .net core 2.1.4 -

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
                {                
                    options.ClientId = "xxx-xxxxx-xxxx";
                    options.Authority = "xxx-xxxxx-xxxx";
                    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
                        {
                            ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = $"https://reverse_proxy_url/app_name/service_name{options.CallbackPath}";

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };

                });
```